# Proper package naming for testing with the Go language

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have seen several different test package naming strategies within Go and wanted to know what pros and cons of each are and which one I should use.

**Strategy 1:**

File name: `github.com/user/myfunc.go`

```
package myfunc
```

Test file name: `github.com/user/myfunc_test.go`

```
package myfunc
```

See [bzip2](http://golang.org/src/pkg/compress/bzip2/bzip2_test.go) for an example.

**Strategy 2:**

File name: `github.com/user/myfunc.go`

```
package myfunc
```

Test file name: `github.com/user/myfunc_test.go`

```
package myfunc_test

import (
    "github.com/user/myfunc"
)
```

See [wire](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/blob/master/wire/msgtx_test.go) for an example.

**Strategy 3:**

File name: `github.com/user/myfunc.go`

```
package myfunc
```

Test file name: `github.com/user/myfunc_test.go`

```
package myfunc_test

import (
    . "myfunc"
)
```

See [strings](http://golang.org/src/pkg/strings/search_test.go) for an example.

The Go standard library seems to use a mixture of strategy 1 and 2. Which of all three should I use? It's a pain appending `package *_test` to my testing packages as it means I can't test my package private methods but maybe there is a hidden advantage I am not aware of?

Comment: This question is only going to result in varying opinions, but I'll throw in mine. You shouldn't need to test your private methods. You want to test the interface of your package that other developers will consume. If the tests fail then you know your private methods need a look.

Comment: The [wire]( https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/blob/master/wire/msgtx_test.go) example for Strategy 2, is actually now also an example of Strategy 1...

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with writing test cases for a private function. If it has an isolated functionality (which it should) then it makes sense to write its own tests. Some reasons: a) it makes it easier to replace it in the future if needed b) you know you don't need to find bugs in this, just in its callers c) it helps writing more focused tests for the caller function. Therefore, I think Strategy 1 is the best.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

The fundamental difference between the three strategies you've listed is whether or not the test code is in the same package as the code under test. The decision to use `package myfunc` or `package myfunc_test` in the test file depends on whether you want to perform [white-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) or [black-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) testing.

There's nothing wrong with using both methods in a project. For instance, you could have `myfunc_whitebox_test.go` and `myfunx_blackbox_test.go`.

### Test Code Package Comparison

- **Black-box Testing:** Use `package myfunc_test`, which will ensure you're only using the [exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).
- **White-box Testing:** Use `package myfunc` so that you have access to the non-exported identifiers. Good for unit tests that require access to non-exported variables, functions, and methods.

### Comparison of Strategies Listed in Question

- **Strategy 1:** The file `myfunc_test.go` uses `package myfunc` — In this case the test code in `myfunc_test.go` will be in the same package as the code being tested in `myfunc.go`, which is `myfunc` in this example.
- **Strategy 2:** The file `myfunc_test.go` uses `package myfunc_test` — In this case the test code in `myfunc_test.go` "will be compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary." [Source: Lines 58–59 in the [test.go](http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/test.go) source code]
- **Strategy 3:** The file `myfunc_test.go` uses `package myfunc_test` but imports `myfunc` using the dot notation — This is a variant of Strategy 2, but uses the dot notation to import `myfunc`.

Comment: It should be noted that using Strategy 1 will also keep files with `_test.go` separate than the package being tested (the same behavior as Strategy 2). This doesn't seem to be documented per https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15315

Comment: I saw strong package use Strategy 3, but I can't understand what's the point?

Comment: I forked a package and made changes, and now my tests are all trying to import the original repo instead of my forked package. With Strategy 3, I don't have to change the "github.com/original/link" to "github.com/my/fork", because it's just referencing '.' instead.

Comment: @KevinDeenanauth This just surprised me. I thought I had found a pitfall when I just found a `_test.go` with a non-`_test` package name containing a `func init()` which changes some global package variable for testing. I was wrong.

Comment: @nmarley the `.` doesn't resolve your fork issue. It's not a relative import. It justs imports the identifiers "into the current package".

Answer (score 27):

It depends on the scope of your tests. High level tests (integration, acceptance, etc...) should probably be placed in a separate package to ensure that you are using the package via the exported API.

If you have a large package with a lot of internals that need to be put under test then use the same package for your tests. But that's not an invitation for your tests to access any bit of private state. That would make refactoring a nightmare. [When I write structs in go](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey) I am often implementing interfaces. It is those interface methods that I invoke from my tests, not all of the helper methods/functions individually.

Answer (score 13):

You should use strategy 1 whenever possible. You can use the special `foo_test` package name to avoid import cycles, but that's mostly there so the standard library can be tested with the same mechanism. For example, `strings` cannot be tested with strategy 1 since the `testing` package depends on `strings`. As you said, with strategy 2 or 3 you don't have access to the package's private identifiers, so it's usually better to not use it unless you have to.

Comment: How is not having access to private identifiers in tests not a virtue?

Comment: according to good test practices, you don't test internal implementation details for a code artifact; doing son, is a _code smell_

Comment: It's not always a code smell. You can use whatever strategy best suits you.

Answer (score 4):

One important notes I'd like to add about `import .` from [Golang CodeReviewComments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#import-dot):

The `import .` form can be useful in tests that, due to *circular* dependencies,
cannot be made part of the package being tested:

```
package foo_test

import (
    "bar/testutil" // also imports "foo"
    . "foo"
)
```

In this case, the test file cannot be in package foo because it uses
`bar/testutil`, which imports foo. So we use the 'import .' form to let the file
pretend to be part of package foo even though it is not.

**Except for this one case, do not use `import .`** in your programs.
It makes the programs much harder to read because it is unclear whether a name
like Quux is a top-level identifier in the current package or in an imported package.