# Get Coverage stats when tests are in another package

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-coverage

My tests aren't in the same package as my code. I find this a less cluttered way of organising a codebase with a lot of test files, and I've read that it's a good idea in order to limit tests to interacting via the package's public api.

So it looks something like this:

```
api_client:
    Client.go
    ArtistService.go
    ...
api_client_tests
    ArtistService.Events_test.go
    ArtistService.Info_test.go
    UtilityFunction.go
    ...
```

I can type `go test bandsintown-api/api_client_tests -cover`
and see `0.181s  coverage: 100.0% of statements`. But that's actually just coverage over my `UtilityFunction.go` (as I say when I ran `go test bandsintown-api/api_client_tests -cover=cover.out` and
`go tool cover -html=cover.out`).

**Is there any way to get the coverage for the actual `api_client` package under test, without bringing it all into the same package?**

Comment: Additionally, I'm assuming it's a mistake of mine not to instead use `UtilityFunction_test.go`, even though it contains no tests, because it confuses the coverage?

Comment: I'm going to go track down some opinions on where to put tests. I read to seperate packages [here](https://medium.com/@matryer/5-simple-tips-and-tricks-for-writing-unit-tests-in-golang-619653f90742#.arh8p92aq). But if it's just flagrently wrong and anti-idomatic for go feel free to point that out here. I've also seen it aclaimed as valid on [Proper package naming for testing in Go Lang](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31443271/1734730)

Comment: If you want to test the exported interface of `package api` only your test typically live in `package api_test` but the files are kept in the same folder (here api_client) and coverage should work. I never saw this separation into two different folders.

Comment: Try with -cover -coverpkg "api_client" "api_client_tests"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it is mentioned in comments you can run

`go test -cover -coverpkg "api_client" "api_client_tests"`

to run the tests with coverage.

But splitting code files from tests files to a different directories isn't a Go's way.

I suppose that you want to have a black-box testing(nothing package-private stuff can be accessible outside, even for tests).

To accomplish this it's allowed to have tests in another package(without moving the files). Example:

api_client.go

```
package api_client

// will not be accessible outside of the package
var privateVar = 10

func Method() {
}
```

api_client_test.go

```
package api_client_tests

import "testing"

func TestClient(t *testing.T) {
    Method()
}
```