# Golang package test coverage not working in version 1.10.1

Tags: go

I'm trying to generate test coverage for a package using the following commands.

`go test -v ./models_test -coverpkg=./models -coverprofile=c.out && go tool cover -func=c.out`

`go test -v ./models_test -coverpkg=github.com/apremalal/go-test-cov/models -coverprofile=c.out && go tool cover -func=c.out`

My repo structure is like below, and I'm executing commands indie  folder

```
<go-test-cov>
 |
  -<models>
 |
  -<models-test>
```

I have hosted the code in [github](https://github.com/apremalal/go-test-cov) for easy referencing.

models/math.go

```
package models

func Add(x,y int) int{
  return x+y
}
```

models_test/math_test.go

```
package models_test

import (
    "testing"
  "github.com/apremalal/go-test-cov/models"
)

func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
    total := models.Add(5, 5)
    if total != 10 {
       t.Errorf("Sum was incorrect, got: %d, want: %d.", total, 10)
    }
}
```

Each time I receive 0% test coverage though the tests get executed without errors.

I'm using go version `go1.10.1 darwin/amd64`. This method used to work in earlier go versions. Appreciate your help in finding out how to get this working with the latest go release.

Comment: Include your relevant code in the question.

Comment: @Flimzy updated the question

Comment: Move `models_test/math_test.go` to `models/math_test.go`.

Comment: @fhe I know it works inside the same package. I want to keep the test cases outside of the package to keep things clean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Coverage stats when tests are in another package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464156/get-coverage-stats-when-tests-are-in-another-package)

Comment: @PatrickStephen That one doesn't work for me with latest go version. It throws a warning `warning: no packages being tested depend on matches for pattern models` and give 0% test coverage.