# Go Coverage not including functions in other package

Tags: go

I have a project like this:

```
app/
    api/
        foo.go
        test_foo.go
src/
    db/
        bar.go
```

In `foo.go`, a call is made to a function in `bar.go`. However, when running the coverage report, it shows that 0 lines of bar.go are covered.

Is there a way to get coverage to include function call to other packages?

In my case, I do not want to make separate tests for `db` and for `api`, since all calls through `db` will always go through `api`, and it would be redundant to write two tests.

I'm running the coverage like this:

```
go clean -testcache
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./...
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Coverage stats when tests are in another package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464156/get-coverage-stats-when-tests-are-in-another-package)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to include the `coverpkg` flag so:

```
 go test -coverpkg=./... coverprofile=coverage.out ./...
```

Would calculate the coverage on all of your packages.

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags

Comment: When I ran this, it said my `bar.go` file had 0% coverage in the command line. However when I opened the HTML, the bar.go's coverage was greater than 0%.

Comment: Yeah, it does that! What the command line prints is when running the API test what is the coverage for all packages then when running the db test (ie no tests) what is the coverage for all packages. The html file then contains total coverage from all tests run

Answer (score 2):

Short answer. To see correct coverages run:

```
go test ./... -coverprofile=coverage.out -coverpkg=./...
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

And then see percentages in dropdown inside browser.

---

**Longer answer** with explanation why other ways not worked. So, I also have a project with `api` and `store` (in this question it is called `db`) packages, where `store` is used in `api`, and I have tests in `api`.

```
go test -cover ./...
```

Says that `api` is covered, `store` - "[no test files]".

When I run it like

```
go test -cover -coverpkg=./... ./...
```

It decreases coverage in `api` because now that number means how testcases in `api` package cover all the packages, which is not very useful number.

But there is a way to know how given package is covered by tests in all the packages (eg, how `store` is covered by tests from `api` and other places).

First, you generate coverage profile:

```
go test ./... -coverprofile=coverage.out -coverpkg=./...
```

Above command will still give you wrong percents in output, but it will create `coverage.out` file that will list all the lines in all packages covered by tests in all packages.

Then you could view this report in the browser with the command:

```
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

Then in the dropdown that allows you to select files to browse coverage for, you will get correct per file coverages.

Comment: `go tool cover -html` groups coverage by file and `go tool cover -func` groups by function. Do you know of any way to group coverage by package like it does in `go test`?