# Golang test package circular dependency problem

Tags: go, testing

Suppose I have two packages, `foo` and `bar` (and thus, `foo.go`, `foo_test.go`, `bar.go`, and `bar_test.go`.) `bar` depends on `foo`. In `bar_test.go`, I want to use some faked types that are defined in `foo_test.go`. But since it isn't allowed for `*_test.go` files to export types, I moved them into a test package for `foo`, ie `footest`, that both `foo` and `bar` depend on.

Suppose `foo.go` has some interfaces like this:

```
type A interface {
   AFunc() err
}

type B interface {
   BFunc() (A, error)
}
```

and in `footest.go`, I want to implement these interfaces with fakes:

```
type FakeA struct {}

type FakeB struct {}

func (fa *FakeA) AFunc() error {
   // this does something
}

func (fb *FakeB) BFunc() (A, error) {
   // this does something and returns an instance of A
}
```

This doesn't work, because it creates a circular dependency. `foo` depends on `footest`, but `footest` also needs to depend on `foo` in order to reference `A`.

Am I missing some kind of best practice that would enable me to avoid this problem? I was under the impression that creating test packages, like `footest`, is the standard practice when test files need to use faked types in other packages, but I would love to be corrected if there's a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

package `foo` will not depend on package `footest` as long as you use `package foo_test` in your foo_test.go file. In that case, foo_test will be compiled as a separate package. However, you won't have access to non-exported types in `package foo`.

e.g.

foo.go

```
package foo

type A interface {
   AFunc() err
}

type B interface {
   BFunc() (A, error)
}
```

foo_test.go

```
package foo_test

// Add tests after importing package footest and foo
```

[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998250/proper-package-naming-for-testing-with-the-go-language/31443271#31443271) for more details on the package naming.

Comment: I didn't realize it was ever within best practices to put test code in a different package than the code under test. Thank you!

Comment: Access to non-exported type could be resolved by adding a file ex. `export_test.go` in package `foo` which changes non-exported type to exported type. Ex. `var FooExportedType = fooNonExportedType` . 
An Example is in go language source https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19:src/io/export_test.go